# How to ask PowerShell to copy identify duplicate & put their answer as comma separated?

Tags: powershell

I have below script which creating multiple xml based on the feed from one of the CSV file, now my csv have multiple duplicate row but with different column value, how to change something in below powershell to club duplicate row value but comma separate its column value in xml.

[image]

**output xml I want to see - NameA = 20, 30, 90**

PowerShell Code is as -

```
$data = Import-Csv .\data.csv
$luTable = @{}

# Create Keys in Lookup Table
$data | % {
    if (!$luTable.ContainsKey("$($_.data1)")) { $luTable["$($_.data2)"] = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList }
}

$luTable.Keys | % {
    $key = $_ # Store Key
    $data | where data2 -Match $_ | select data1 | % {
        $luTable[$key].Add($_.data1)
    }
}

# Build XML Files

$luTable.Keys | % {
    $key = $_

    $filetext = gc ".\template.xml"
    $filetext = $filetext.Replace("##PARAMNAME##", $key)

    $targets = ""
    
    $luTable[$key] | % {
        $targets += "<DataColumn1>$($_)</DataColumn1>"
    }

    $filetext = $filetext.Replace("##DATACOLUMNS##", $targets)

    sc -Path ".\$($key).xml" -Value $filetext
}
```

**Sample Master XML -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SingleAction>
        <Title>Setting Data Group - **##PARAMNAME##**</Title>
        <Relevance>(if exists property "in proxy agent context" then (not in proxy agent context) else true)</Relevance>
        
        code..
        
        code..
        

        <Parameter Name="Data ID">**##PARAMNAME##**</Parameter>
        <Settings>
        lots of other settings
        settings
        setttings
        ..
        ..
    
        <Target>
            ##DATACOLUMNS##
        </Target>
```

Desired output for duplicate entries--- should be something like below-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <SingleAction>
            <Title>Setting Data Group - 20, 30, 90</Title>
            <Relevance>(if exists property "in proxy agent context" then (not in proxy agent context) else true)</Relevance>
            
            code..
            
            code..
            
    
            <Parameter Name="Data ID">20, 30, 90</Parameter>
            <Settings>
            lots of other settings
            settings
            setttings
            ..
            ..
        
            <Target>
                <DataColumn1>NameA</DataColumn1>
            </Target>
```

Desired output if not duplicate like below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <SingleAction>
            <Title>Setting Data Group - 2</Title>
            <Relevance>(if exists property "in proxy agent context" then (not in proxy agent context) else true)</Relevance>
            
            code..
            
            code..
            
    
            <Parameter Name="Data ID">2</Parameter>
            <Settings>
            lots of other settings
            settings
            setttings
            ..
            ..
        
            <Target>
                <DataColumn1>NameC</DataColumn1>
            </Target>
```

Comment: Show us your template.xml and a better example of the desired output.

Comment: Master xml sample added in original post.

Comment: also posted some output for better understanding, all output with duplicate & no duplicate based on the picture which I pasted 1st for excel table Data1 & Data2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are over-complicating this.

Just fix your template.xml so that the `<SingleAction>` node is closed with `</SingleAction>`.

Then read the data from the csv file, and use `Group-Object` to get all data belonging to whatever is under `Data1` column as collection.

```
$template = Get-Content -Path 'D:\Test\template.xml' -Raw

Import-Csv -Path 'D:\Test\data.csv' | Group-Object Data1 | ForEach-Object {
    # replace the placeholders in the template. Sort the numeric values for neatness as we go.
    $template -replace '##PARAMNAME##', (([int[]]$_.Group.Data2 | Sort-Object) -join ', ') -replace 
                       '##DATACOLUMNS##', "<DataColumn1>$($_.Name)</DataColumn1>" |
    Set-Content -Path "D:\Test\$($_.Name).xml" -Encoding UTF8
}
```

Output example **NameA.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SingleAction>
        <Title>Setting Data Group - 20, 30, 90</Title>
        <Relevance>(if exists property "in proxy agent context" then (not in proxy agent context) else true)</Relevance>
        
        code..
        
        code..
        

        <Parameter Name="Data ID">20, 30, 90</Parameter>
        <Settings>
        lots of other settings
        settings
        setttings
        ..
        ..
    
        <Target>
            <DataColumn1>NameA</DataColumn1>
        </Target>
    </SingleAction>
```

Output example **NameC.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <SingleAction>
        <Title>Setting Data Group - 2</Title>
        <Relevance>(if exists property "in proxy agent context" then (not in proxy agent context) else true)</Relevance>
        
        code..
        
        code..
        

        <Parameter Name="Data ID">2</Parameter>
        <Settings>
        lots of other settings
        settings
        setttings
        ..
        ..
    
        <Target>
            <DataColumn1>NameC</DataColumn1>
        </Target>
    </SingleAction>
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion - "Just fix your template.xml so that the <SingleAction> node is closed with </SingleAction>" its already there in my xml file, I posted just sample one removing lost of unwanted junk.      Your script is doing what I were looking but still one problem is there, by running your script changes I am able to get the comma separated  Data2 values for Data1 but script is creating single single xml for each data1 even if there is no comma separated value for data1 in data2.

Comment: it should be creating one xml file for comma separated value if duplicate is there & group the data1 if multiple data1 value are associated with single data2 value - like below-  Data1 Data2
NameX 30
NameY 30
Namez 30

Comment: @Vijaykhurava. Your last comment makes no sense to me.. The code produces your desired output **exactly**. Now you want something different? You should have made that clear in the question.

Comment: I really appreciate what you updated & that worked without any issue but its not different from what I have asked, I am sorry if you are thinking it was not clear but please think of number of XML if we have 50000 entries in csv file & if I run your script it will group all comma separated entries for some of the data1 values but it will create thousands of separate XML files for each data1 value against data2 even if 50000 data2 value are same for data1 values right ?

Comment: let me update it right if you are thinking its not clear, 1. data1 value should be grouped in xml if data2 value are same for them, 2. data1 value should be grouped in xml if data2 value are comma separated for them.

Comment: just to get the desired results, I have asked another question related to it if you can please look & answer there - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63787676/how-to-group-csv-data-in-xml

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
$luTable[$key] | % {
    $targets += "<DataColumn1>$($_)</DataColumn1>"
}
```

to create just a single node with all the values in `$luTable[$key]`:

```
$targets = "<DataColumn1>$($luTable[$key] -join ',')</DataColumn1>"
```

Comment: Its creating mess if I add your code in between <DataColumn1></DataColumn1>, its made for data1 column from the sheet, I want data2 column to be comma separated only. if you please look into my picture highlighted one are duplicates where Data1 is actual duplicate but Data2 value is not, lets say data1 is computername and data2 is setting to be more clear to understand.